# Inspecting jQuery usage

Tags: jquery

I like a jQuery animation done on a website and I want to discover how they are doing it. Is it possible to inspect jQuery of a website you don't own? What tool do I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because javascript is interpreted on the client (the browser), it is viewable by looking at the source. It is often in the `<head>` tag or at the bottom of the `<body>` tag, in a `<script>` tag. It is possible that the javascript is in a different file, which is indicated by the `href` attribute.

It is possible however that the source is minified. This means that the variable names are replaced with really small names, like `a`, and all the whitespace and comments are removed. This makes it a lot harder to read the source, but there are tools out there to format the script and make it more readable. You won't get the variable names and comments back though.

Answer (score 1):

you can use firebug, chrome development tools, IE development tools, or even fiddler to achieve this.
Simply viewing the source of the webpage might even get you there as well.